# How to encode a HEVC video from YUV420 Mat data (from a hardware triggered camera) via FFmpeg in Python

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, hevc

I am having problems encoding a HEVC video from a series of YUV420 Mat data via FFmpeg.

1. I am using python in Ubuntu-20.04;
2. I am retrieving frame data from a hardware triggered camera (BASLER), using pypylon;
3. I want to write a video from that camera in HEVC codec, using my GPU-NVENC;
4. I guess I have to use FFmpeg to achieve these;

What I have tried:

1. I find that FFmpeg supports encoding from a camera, but it seems to only support webcams, not the camera I use (hardware triggered BASLER cameras with pypylon APIs);
2. I find that FFmpeg supports transfering a video from one codec to another, which is not my case;
3. I find that FFmpeg supports encoding a video from a series of jpeg images. But in my case, it will be inefficient if I first save each frame into a picture and then encode them into a video;
4. The frame data retrieved from camera can be converted to YUV420 (directly from pypylon), which is suitable for HEVC encoding;
5. I learnt that the basic unit in FFmpeg to encode a video is AVFrame. I guess I have to first turn my YUV420 data into AVFrame, then encode AVFrames into HEVC;
6. But I do not know how to achieve that in python.

My simplified and expected codes:

```
camera = pylon.InstantCamera(tlf.CreateFirstDevice())
converter = pylon.ImageFormatConverter()
converter.OutputPixelFormat = pylon.PixelType_YUV420
video_handle = xxxxxx  # HEVC
while True:
    grabResult = camera.RetrieveResult(timeout, pylon.TimeoutHandling_ThrowException)
    image = converter.Convert(grabResult).GetArray()
    video_handle.write(frame)  # encode into a hevc video via ffmpeg in NVENC
```

Comment: Please add your [mcve] for capturing frames from your Basler.

Comment: So, is your question *"What is xxxxx in `video_handle = xxxxx`"* ?

Comment: No. "video_handle = xxxxx" and "video_handle.write(frame)" is what I expect, like what OpenCV does. But I have completely no idea of how FFmpeg does this, or maybe FFmpeg cannot do this.

Comment: Plus, from what I know, OpenCV also uses FFmpeg for video-writing like AVI etc. But OpenCV just does not support HEVC encoding. That is why I post this question.

Comment: So use `sp = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg', options], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)` then write your frame as RGB/YUV or whatever you like into `ffmpeg` with `sp.stdin.write()`.

Comment: Cool - glad it works. Consider writing an answer and adding your new, improved code so others in the Stack Overflow community can also benefit.